# Lib folder gets packaged with eclipse plugin jar while building through tycho

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho, p2

I am trying to build eclipse plugin using tycho-compiler-plugin from maven.
I have resolved many bundled dependencies from p2 repo. I have some jar dependencies which are present in bundle-classpath in manifest.mf -

```
  Bundle-ClassPath: .,
    lib/test1.jar,
    lib/test2.jar
```

These jars are present in lib folder which is present at root level i.e where pom is present.

POM file looks like -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.test.plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>0.0.0</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

    <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>Mars</id>
         <layout>p2</layout>
         <url>file:///E:/repo/eclipseRepo/</url>
      </repository>
   </repositories>
   <build>
      <directory>../../../../target</directory>
      <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.25.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.25.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
           <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>0.25.0</version>
           <configuration>
              <buildDirectory>../../../../plugin</buildDirectory>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Now ti builds eclipse plugin properly , but while packaging it also includes lib folder. Attached jar screenshot - 
[image]
I want to exclude this lib folder from jar.I have tried configuration in tycho-packaging-jar plugin to exclude it. But not working. How to exclude it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `<directory>` or `<buildDirectory>` outside the current project’s base directory looks fairly non-standard. In fact, I have never had the need to explicit configure either of these – or `<sourceDirectory>`, for that matter. That’s what the `build.properties` file is for, which is the default way to configure these things in both Eclipse PDE and Tycho.

From the screenshot it looks like there is no `build.properties` file present. I would suggest you configure the various locations through [its properties](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/BuildProperties.html) rather than through POM elements. Something along the lines of [this example](http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho-demo.git/tree/itp01/tycho.demo.itp01/build.properties), with `bin.includes` and `bin.excludes` handling your JAR inclusions.

Comment: Thank you. Editing  build.properties resolved the issue.